# Printing a PHP variable into the console by using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to print out the value of a PHP variable in the browser's console by using jQuery and AJAX. The `$.ajax` function seems to be the way. The main problem is that I don't know what am I supposed to assign to the `data` parameter and what to pass as the `success` function parameter.

This is the PHP file:

```
<?php
    $foo = "Hello, World!";
?>
```

And this is my attempt at AJAX:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Lorem ipsum</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            $.ajax({
                url: "../scr/main.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: /* What am I supposed to put here? */
                success: function(/* And what am I supposed to put here? */) {
                    console.log(/* The value of $foo */);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking each line in turn:

> data: /* What am I supposed to put here? */

`data` should contain the data you want to *send* to the PHP file. In your case you are not sending any so it can be omitted. If you did want to send data, use an object like this:

```
data: { foo: 'bar' }
```

Then you would read it from your PHP like this:

```
$_POST['foo'] // = 'bar'
```

---

> success: function(/* And what am I supposed to put here? */) {

The `success` handler function accepts the content of the response as an argument. As such, you can provide any valid variable name. Generally 'response' is used.

---

To actually return the information I would suggest you use a formal data structure as returning plain text has a lot of pitfalls which can cause issues. A common choice for this is to use JSON.

To return JSON from PHP simply use `json_encode`. This will return the message you require with a key you can use to access it through the `response` object in the `success` function.

Putting all that together looks like this:

```oho
<?php
  $foo = "Hello, World!"
  echo json_encode(array('message' => $foo));
?>
```

```js
$.ajax({
  url: "../scr/main.php",
  type: "POST",
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(response.message);
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your PHP code with the `$.ajax` function, but it doesn't do anything. The console says, that line 15, which has this chunk of code `console.log(response.message);` is undefined.

EDIT: I fixed it. I had to replace the function parameter parameter and the `console.log` value with `message`.

Comment: I have one more question. The content loaded with the `$.ajax` function completely replaced all original content on the page (headers, paragraphs etc.). Can I somehow load the AJAX content without it replacing anything on the page?